# notation: stems in different direction

Tags: notation, performance-practice

Should I play G on the  twice or hold it ? I’m confused how to play the right hand. Help me. Thanks  [image]

Comment: You hold the G, and all the other dotted quavers. In fact, as you'll need to pedal in order to hold those low notes in the left hand, they will be sustained. anyway. Some crafty pedalling is called for. (Or 'pedaling' in the US.)

Comment: This must be a dupe. This sort of question crops up monthly.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian, I'm not a piano player, so I have to ask: why? I don't see any legato signs.

Comment: What key is this in, with those accidental E#s? Can't work out what the triads are!

Comment: @Pyromonk Why what? Are you asking why that G is held? Because of its length. Or are you asking why the pedal is needed? It's needed to sustain the two dotted minims. The left hand can't hold those while playing the quavers, only the first and seventh of which would be within reach.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian, thank you, I appreciate that. I didn't understand what you meant in your original response, and this helped clear it up for me. Sorry, just being curious.

Comment: Something with sharps in. I'd go for F#  minor. I called them Gs 'cos the OP did.

Comment: @Pyromonk. Not at all. And you're welcome! Did I sound ratty? Didn't mean to.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian, oh, not at all, I was just trying to apologise for the inconvenience. I do not play piano, but I like to learn as much as I can about other instruments and how to interpret their scores, because I think it's vital to playing music with others (and, like I said, I am incessantly curious).

Comment: @Tim, I've mostly seen E# in D# minor pieces.

Comment: @Pyromonk - wouldn't D#m key already have E# in its key sig.? F#m sounds feasible, as the sharpened leading note, needing to be an accidental.

Comment: @Tim, that's my bad, I was too tired and sleepy. E# appears in F# harmonic minor (the raised 7th), like OldBrixtonian has stated before. I saw his response and automatically transposed F# to its relative minor, for some odd reason.